# poll won't return the same result if embedded in a multiprocessing.Process as in the main script

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, multiprocessing

I want to read in a non blocking way the output of an external program run concurrently with my python code. To launch the program (netcat for instance), I use subprocess.Popen and bind its stdout and stderr to subprocess.PIPE. I then launch a multiprocessing.Process that has the mission to check if that program is still running (proc.poll() ) and if it is, it tries to read from its pipes. My problem is that "proc.poll()" always return 0 in the "listen_to_fds" function but works perfectly well in the "call" function (which is the main function), that is proc.poll() returns None (the application I launch never finishes so that's the correct return value).

I call the following functions with :
     call ("./test.sh")

## My module

```
def listen_to_fds(logger,proc):
  while proc.poll() is None:
    print("program still running", proc.returncode)
    data = proc.stdout.read()
    if data:
        print("Data", data)
    time.sleep(1)

print("last check", proc.returncode )



def call(cli ):

logger = logging.getLogger("isix.daemon")
cli_args = shlex.split(cli)

proc = subprocess.Popen(
        cli_args
        ,stdout=subprocess.PIPE 
        ,stderr=subprocess.PIPE
        )


set_fd_as_nonblocking( proc.stdout )
set_fd_as_nonblocking( proc.stderr )

pipe2 = multiprocessing.Process( 
    target=listen_to_fds,
    args=( logger, proc )
    )
while proc.poll() is None:
   print("program still running", proc.returncode)
   data = proc.stdout.read()
   if data:
         print("Data", data)
   time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subprocess `poll` function uses the OS's `wait` call (in non-blocking mode, usually `wait4`) which requires that the process doing the "wait" be the parent of the process being awaited.

You cannot gather the return code in anything other than the direct parent either, but you *can* check for any process's existence by sending signal `0` (zero), using `os.kill`.  If you are allowed to send signals, and the process exists, `os.kill(pid, 0)` succeeds (without affecting the other process).  If you are not allowed to send signals (the process exists but belongs to another user), `os.kill(pid, 0)` raises an `OSError` with `EPERM` as its `errno`.  If the process no longer exists, `os.kill(pid, 0)` raises an `OSError` with `ESRCH` as its `errno`.  (There's a "window of badness" that occurs if the process finishes while you are not looking, and then the parent of that process collects it, making the process-ID available for reuse, and then your same user-ID starts a new, unrelated process that gets the same process-ID—but process-IDs are not recycled very quickly, on purpose, so this is not very likely.)

On the whole, though, it's best to take some other approach to this, such as using `select` or `epoll` or similar, to decide when to read data.

Comment: Despite my researches I couldn't find that piece of information that explained it all: "the process doing the "wait" be the parent of the process being awaited.". I've organized my code differently and it works as intended. Thanks a lot